# How to render the parent component in the child component using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a parent component which when rendered opens up the child component.
But I want to give a `back button` in the child component such that when I click on it, it goes back to the parent component page opens up *without giving a query parameter*.
Can someone please help me find a solution for this using React and typescript?

Comment: Maybe you could try [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways by which you can do this:

1. You can add an onClick event on back button and redirect it to parent component route(if parent and child component are on different routes)
2. If parent and child component is being rendered on the same route, then you can pass a callback function to child as a prop, which regulates the display of child component.

Something like this:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            showChild: true
        }
    }
    handleChildComponent = () => {
        this.setState({showChild: false})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.showChild && <ChildComponent handleChildComponent={this.handleChildComponent}/> }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
    
export default function Child  {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={props.handleChildComponent}></Button>
            </div>
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Routers History for this purpose. History contains a `goBack` method. For Typescript support you can add `@types/react-router`. Hopefully this answers your question.